# Web Farm Framework Excluding Folders

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2

Currently getting to grips with Web Farm Framewor and ARR. The Primary and Secondary servers are syncing from Primary to Secondary as they should be. However, there is a cache folder that is being synced which in turn causes the Secondary server to become unhealthy.

So was hoping somebody could explain how to exclude folders from syncing between the 2 servers if possible.

Cheers
Jamie

Answer (score 3):

[Try this page](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1012/skipping-folders-while-provisioning-with-web-farm-framework-20-for-iis-7/)

> To exclude folders from provisioning
>
> 1. On the controller machine, open the ApplicationHost.config file. This is
>      under the directory
>      %windir%\System\inetsrv\config.
> 2. Under the applicationProvision element, add an entry to skip the
>      directives as follows
>
>    ```
>    <webFarms>
>        <webFarm serverAutoStart="false" name="Farm"
>    enabled="true"
>    adminUserName="{0}\administrator"
>    adminPassword=”pwd” 
>    primaryServer="demo-primary">
>            <server address="demo-primary" enabled="true" />
>            <server address="demo-secondary" enabled="true" />
>            <platformProvision syncPlatformFromPrimary="true" />
>            <applicationProvision syncWebServerFromPrimary="true">
>                <skipDirectives>
>                    <skip name="folder1" skipDirective="objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=.*folder1.*" />
>                </skipDirectives>
>            </applicationProvision>
>        </webFarm>
>    </webFarms>
>    ```
> 3. When you save the changes, Web Farms Framework immediately picks up
>      the changes from the configuration
>      file and does application
>      provisioning.
> 4. Verify that the secondary servers provisioned only Folder2, and Folder1
>      was excluded.
> 5. You can also skip binding as follows:
>      `<skip name="folder1" skipDirective="attributes.protocol=https" />`
> 6. Alternatively, you can sync a specific directory using the msdeploy
>      command directly for each secondary
>      server as follows:
>
>    ```
>    C:\>cmd.exe /c ""%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Microsoft Web
>    Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync
>    -source:contentPath="Default Web Site",computerName=demo-primary
>    -dest:contentPath="Default Web Site" -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=.*folder1.*"
>    ```

Comment: @Antino - Welcome to Server Fault! Just a tip, it's generally a good idea to include the important excerpt from the page you've linked to, as links on the internet go dead all the time (esp. links from iis.net as they seem to re-structure their URLs all the time). I've added it in for you.